# laravel Fatal Error

Tags: php, laravel-4, fatal-error

I'm getting a fatal error that seems to makes no sense to me on the global $companies variable... Any thoughts?

Error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Code:

```
public function getCreate(){
            $view = View::make('account.create');
            global $companies = DB::table('homes')->select('Company')->distinct()->get(array());
            return $view->with('companies', $companies)->with('home_names', $home_names);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `global` keyword can only be use to declare global scope for a variable. You cannot simultaneously use an operator on that variable in the same statement.

So, try this instead:

```
global $companies;
$companies = DB::table('homes')->select('Company')->distinct()->get(array());
```